# Add one to a function call in python

Tags: python, function

What does the last line, return 1 + .... do ?  How can you return 1 plus a function call?

Below is the assignments text:

> These functions recursively count the number of instances of the key in the target string

```
def countSubStringMatchRecursive(target, key):
    currentPosition = find(target, key)
    if find(target, key) == -1:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + countSubStringMatchRecursive(target[currentPosition+1:], key)
```

Comment: Please mark your homework with the [homework] tag.

Comment: Three answers tells this is recursion although identifier "countSubStringMatchRecursive" matches "Recursive" as substring.

Comment: This isn't really homework for school, It's the open course ware from MIT.

Comment: "open course ware from MIT"  Sounds like homework to me.

Comment: @S.Lott: NoahClark asked for an explanation of a concept unknown to him, not for the solution to the assigned problem; without being sure, I think the tag “homework” is not necessary here: the question would be valid even if Noah found the code in a programming book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line isn't returning "1 plus a function call", it is returning 1 + the return value of the function, which is either `0` or `1` depending on whether the condition has been met.

It is recursive, in that the return value from the function call will be 1 + the return value of another function call -- again, and again, and again, until `find(target, key) == -1`.

Think of it more like:

`return 1 + ( 1 + (1 + (1 + (0))))`

Answer (score 1):

Its best to think of this from the end case. Lets say you have 3 possible matches. The calls would like this,

```
countSubStringMatchRecursive(target, key)

  (The find operation is not -1, so call again)
  1 + countSubStringMatchRecursive(target, key)

    (The find operation is not -1, so call again)
    1 + countSubStringMatchRecursive(target, key)

      In this end case, the find operation is -1, so this function returns a 0.

    Return value at this level is now 1 + 0 = 1

  Return value at this level is now 1 + 1 = 2

 Return value at the topmost level is now 1 + 2 = 3
```

So as you can see, the 1+ function call is basically a way to keep track of the count.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you showed does this:

```
currentPosition = find(target, key)
if find(target, key) == -1:
```

when it should be doing this:

```
currentPosition = find(target, key)
if currentPosition == -1:
```

If your teacher actually wrote that code, it's time to change schools!

Comment: No, my teacher didn't write it.  Another student did, and I looking through the code of all the students and didn't understand the 1 +